# Adjust d3 tree layout zoom effect and also how to move to certain position on the tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

- After I applied zoom effect on tree layout I found that the zoom in,
  always start from the center not from the position the mouse stop and
  also on mobile devices not from the position my finger touch so how
  can I adjust the zoom effect to make it start from those positions
  and when i start to use event.transform i found the tree start to make
  weird movement when i try to zoom in or out and some times the tree move
  outside the window and disappear, that's why i only use event.transform.k
- the Second thing is how can i pick the coordinates of every member
  position on the tree so i can use them in a function when invoked it took
  me directly to member position in the tree

```js
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

const Tree = ({familyData,isProfile}) => {
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null)
    const history = useHistory()
    const radialPoint = (x, y) => {
        return [(y = +y) * Math.cos(x -= Math.PI / 2), y * Math.sin(x)];
    }
    const genColors = [
            '#000','#7d1e01', '#2c3e50',
            '#80016e','#673ab7',
            '#ff9800','#795548','#142796',
            '#61b301','#19a0b1','#a0342c',
            '#CEE397','#F5A25D','#625261',
            '#87556F','#E5EDB7','#231E23',
            '#6F0000','#FFF0F5','#FFEBD9',
            '#BEEBE9','#B0A160','#E4F9FF',
        ]
    
    const createTree = () => {
        wrapperRef.current.innerHTML = '';
        const margin = {top: 140, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0}
        const innerHeight = 2000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        const zoomHandler = event =>{
            return `scale(${event.transform.k})`
        }
        const svg = d3.select(wrapperRef.current)
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', 4000)
                    .attr('height', 2250)
                    .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 5]).on('zoom', (event) => {
                        svg.attr('transform', zoomHandler(event))
                    }))
        const width = +svg.attr("width")
        const height = +svg.attr("height")
        const g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${(width/2+ 40)},${(height-150)})`);
        
        const dataStructure = d3.stratify().id(d => d._id).parentId(d => d.parentId)(familyData)
        const treeLayout = d3.tree().size([(1 * Math.PI), innerHeight])
        const root = treeLayout(dataStructure)
        
        
        g.selectAll(".link")
            .data(root.links())
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', '#555')
            .attr('stroke-opacity', '0.4')
            .attr('stroke-width', (d) => {
                if(d.target.depth <= 9){
                    return 10 - d.target.depth
                } else {
                    return 1
                }
            })
            .attr("d", d3.linkRadial()
            .angle(d => d.x-Math.PI/2)
            .radius(d => d.y))
            .attr('id',  d => 'link_' + d.target.data._id)
            .attr('stroke-dasharray', function(){
                const length = this.getTotalLength()
                return `${length} ${length}`
            })
            .attr('stroke-dashoffset', function(){
                const length = this.getTotalLength()
                return length
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.source.depth * 500)
            .attr('stroke-dashoffset', 0)

        const node = g.selectAll(".node")
            .data(root.descendants())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", d => d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf")
            .attr('transform', d =>  "translate(" + radialPoint(d.x-Math.PI/2, d.y) + ")");
            node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", d => 15 - (d.depth))
            .style("stroke","white")
             .style("fill", d => {   
                if(d.children){
                    return genColors[d.depth]
                } else {
                    return '#04a21a'
                }
            })
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
        
        node.append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", d => !d.children ? "image/leaf.png":"")
            .attr('x', '-15px')
            .attr('y', d => "-150px")
            .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${(d.x > Math.PI/2 ? d.x-Math.PI/2  : d.x-Math.PI/2 ) * 180 / Math.PI})`)
            // .attr('transform', d => `rotate(-50, -20, -100)`)
            .attr('width', '2.5rem')
            .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.depth * 500)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
            
        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy","0.2em")
            .attr('y', d => {
                if(d.depth === 0 || d.depth === 1){
                    return 10
                }else {
                    return 2
                }
            })
            .attr("x", (d) => {
                if(d.depth === 0 || d.depth === 1){
                    return -20
                }else {
                    return d.x > Math.PI/2 && !d.children ? 80 :  -80
                }
            } )
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x > Math.PI/2 === !d.children ? "start" : "end")
            .attr("transform", d => d.depth > 1 && "rotate(" + (d.x > Math.PI/2 ? d.x-Math.PI/2 - Math.PI / 2 : d.x-Math.PI/2 + Math.PI / 2) * 180 / Math.PI + ")")
            .style("font-size", d => 3 - (d.depth * 2) /10 + 'em')
            .text(d => d.data.firstName)
            .attr('id',  d => 'name_' + d.data._id)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .style(' z-index', '9999999')
            .attr('fill', (d) =>{
                if(d.children){
                    return genColors[d.depth]
                } else {
                    return '#04a21a'
                }
            })
            .on('mouseover', (e, d) => {
                d3.selectAll('path').style('stroke', '#2c3e50').style('opacity', 0.2)
                d3.selectAll('text').style('fill', '#2c3e50').style('opacity', 0.2)
                d3.selectAll('circle').style('fill', '#2c3e50').style('opacity', 0.2)
                d3.selectAll('image').style('opacity', '0.1')
                while(d){
                    if(!d.data.parentId ) {
                        d3.select(`#name_${d.data._id}`).style('fill','#000').style('opacity','1')
                    }
                    if(d.data.parentId !== null){
                        d3.select(`#link_${d.data._id}`).style('stroke','#b70202').style('opacity','1')
                        d3.select(`#name_${d.data._id}`).attr('fill','#000').style('opacity','1')
                        .style('font-size', '3rem')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .style('font-size', '5rem');
                    }
                    d = d.parent
                }
            })
            .on('mouseout', () => {
                d3.selectAll('path').style('stroke', '#555').style('opacity','0.4')
                d3.selectAll('text').style('fill', (d) => {
                    if(d.children){
                        return genColors[d.depth]
                    } else {
                        return '#04a21a'
                    }
                }).style('font-size', d => 3 - (d.depth * 2) /10 + 'em').style('opacity','1')
                d3.selectAll('image').style('opacity', '1')
                d3.selectAll('circle').style('fill', (d) => {
                    if(d.children){
                        return genColors[d.depth]
                    } else {
                        return '#04a21a'
                    }
                }).style('opacity','1')
        })
        .on('click', (e, d) => {
            if(!isProfile){
                history.push(`/info/${d.data._id}`)
            } 
        })
        .attr('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .delay(d => d.depth * 600)
            .attr('opacity', 1)
        
       
    }
    useEffect(() => {
       createTree()   
    })
   return (
        <div className="tree__wrapper" ref={wrapperRef}></div>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```